# Java GUI File Menu

Tags: java, user-interface, file, menu

I have a GUI with a Menu named file

how do I Add a file open and close function to the program.  If the program is in the encrypting mode, it should load/save the cleartext text area. If the program is in decrypting mode, it should load/save the ciphertext area.

Comment: Reread that question pretending you know nothing about the project, and ask yourself if that's really something you expect us to be able to answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Adding file open and close methods to an application is typically a fairly basic concept, so I'm going to assume that developing in Java is a new thing for you. In light of that I'll point you to a Java tutorial for GUI development. http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/

Comment: I know how to use JFileChooser but I was asking about how to do decrypt and enrypt mode

Comment: "how do I Add a file open and close function to the program." <-- That's the only part of your post that resembles a question. The rest sounds like a homework assignment or a business requirement that is up to you to figure out.